# Make map breadcrumb trail smooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, mapkit

I have a map that draws a trail based on the users location and movement. It works great as it connects each segment together so I can apply colors based on their speed.  I would like to add where the lines have a smoother look when each segment is joined (about 10 meters) especially on turning.  Below is my code and I can't for the life of me figure out how to add a curve without compromising accuracy.  I also included a screen of what my screen looks like.   I don't have a screen for the final product, but you can see where it connects and image a curve or smooth line.

```
for (int i=0;i<crumbs.pointCount;i++){
            CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

            CGPoint point = [self pointForMapPoint:crumbs.points[i]];
            if (i==0){
                CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, point.x, point.y);

            } else {
                CGPoint prevPoint = [self pointForMapPoint:crumbs.points[i-1]];
                CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, prevPoint.x, prevPoint.y);
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, point.x, point.y);
                CGFloat lineWidth = MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale(zoomScale);
                CGContextAddPath(context, path);

                CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:57 / 255 green:172 / 255 blue:255 / 255 alpha:1].CGColor);

                CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinMiter);
                CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);

                CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
                CGContextStrokePath(context);
                CGPathRelease(path);
            }
```

[image: screen shot]